# class can't be instantiated

Tags: java, graphics, applet

I have a problem with java applet and graphics. I'm trying to run it in Eclipse and it fails.
Im new in java and i hope you can help me.
I have two files: Say.java and SayWhat.java.
Say.java:

```
public class Say {
    SayWhat word = new SayWhat("Hello World");

}
```

SayWhat.java:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SayWhat extends Applet {
     Graphics g;
     String what;
    public SayWhat(String what) {
        this.what=what;
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawString(what, 20, 20);
    }
}
```

Error that appears is:

```
load: SayWhat.class can't be instantiated.
java.lang.InstantiationException: SayWhat
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can you please tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: it's a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444253/presence-of-constructor-in-an-applet-throws-exception)

Comment: 1) I have a problem with java applet and graphics"* Experienced developers have problems with applets, but.. *"Im new in java"* ..that is a recipe for disaster.  Why are you coding an applet rather than a frame?
2) Why use `Applet` rather than `JApplet`?  AWT components (`Applet`) are almost obsolete.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An applet needs to have a public no-arg constructor (either by having an explicit public no-arg constructor, or by having no explicit constructors at all; in the latter case, the compiler will supply a public no-arg constructor as a default). Your class's sole constructor takes an argument:

```
public SayWhat(String what) {
```

so the class can't be instantiated without that argument, so it can't be used as an applet.

Comment: How can i pass the value of my String to a apllet in this case? As I understand, on every object i create - applet is called out with no String value then.

Comment: @user1168085: You can pass it as an "input parameter"; see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/param.html.

Comment: hmm, is there any alternative solutions for that? maybe an easier one.

Comment: @user1168085: That solution might seem complicated at first blush, but if you read through the page, you'll see that it's actually pretty simple. The page mentions lots of things that you *can* do, but very few of them are actually *needed*. Oh, by the way, see http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~amr/121/labs/eclipsetute/applet.html for instructions on passing in a parameter from Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation for [java.lang.InstantiationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/upgrade-guide/article-14.html)

There are two possible causes:

1) Both code and object attributes are specified in the  tag:

```
<APPLET code=MyApplet object=MyApplet.ser width=100 height=100>
</APPLET>
```

The Sun JRE can access either the code or the object attribute, but not both.

2) A code attribute is specified in the  tag, and an object attribute is specified in a  tag :

```
<APPLET code=MyApplet width=100 height=100>
<PARAM name="object" value="someValue">
</APPLET>

public class MyApplet extends java.applet.Applet
{
        public void init()
        {
               String value = getParameter("object");
        }
        ....
}
```

**EDIT**: Add a [default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444253/presence-of-constructor-in-an-applet-throws-exception), as below:

```
public SayWhat() {}
```

Comment: thank you for good reply, added +1 to you. But can you please explain me, how can i pass my string into applet if my contructor doesnt catch any arguments?

Comment: You need to have both constructors.

Answer (score 1):

The Class `SayWhat` should have a public constructor with no arguments.