# Java applet class can't be instantiated

Tags: java, applet

I am new to java and I'm having trouble getting my applet to run. For some reason the class can't be instantiated. I have tried a few things but nothing has helped, I'm really stuck.

Here is the error I'm receiving.

```
load: com.yunatech.pns.chequeprint.HTMLPrinter.class can't be instantiated.
java.lang.InstantiationException: com.yunatech.pns.chequeprint.HTMLPrinter
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my code.

```
package com.yunatech.pns.chequeprint;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.print.Book;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Paper;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class HTMLPrinter extends Applet implements Printable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2343838467856002371L;
    private final JEditorPane printPane;

    public HTMLPrinter(JEditorPane editorPane){
        printPane = editorPane;
    }

    public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex){
        if (pageIndex >= 1) return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)graphics;
        g2d.translate((int)pageFormat.getImageableX(), (int)pageFormat.getImageableY());

        printPane.setSize((int)pageFormat.getImageableWidth(), (int)pageFormat.getImageableHeight());
        printPane.print(g2d);

        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }

    protected static String dump(Paper paper) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(64);
        sb.append(paper.getWidth()).append("x").append(paper.getHeight())
                .append("/").append(paper.getImageableX()).append("x").
                append(paper.getImageableY()).append(" - ").append(paper
                .getImageableWidth()).append("x").append(paper.getImageableHeight());
        return sb.toString();
    }

    protected static String dump(PageFormat pf) {
        Paper paper = pf.getPaper();
        return dump(paper);
    }

    public void main(String[] args){

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Letter wrap test"); 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

        final JEditorPane htmlTextPane = new JEditorPane(); 

        String paramUrl   = getParameter("paramUrl");

        htmlTextPane.setContentType("text/html");
        try {
            htmlTextPane.setPage(paramUrl);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        HTMLPrinter target = new HTMLPrinter(htmlTextPane);

        PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        if (pj.printDialog()) {
            PageFormat pf = pj.defaultPage();
            Paper paper = pf.getPaper();
            double width = 8d * 72d;
            double height = 4d * 72d;
            double margin = 0.1d * 72d;
            paper.setSize(width, height);
            paper.setImageableArea(
                    margin,
                    0,
                    width - (margin * 2),
                    height);
            System.out.println("Before- " + dump(paper));
            pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);
            pf.setPaper(paper);
            System.out.println("After- " + dump(paper));
            System.out.println("After- " + dump(pf));
            dump(pf);
            PageFormat validatePage = pj.validatePage(pf);
            System.out.println("Valid- " + dump(validatePage));

            Book pBook = new Book();
            pBook.append(target, pf);
            pj.setPageable(pBook);

            try {
                pj.print();
            } catch (PrinterException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    } //main

}
```

If anyone could help point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: Applets need a public constructor with no argument. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995114/class-cant-be-instantiated

Answer (score 1):

This is the only constructor you're declaring:

```
public HTMLPrinter(JEditorPane editorPane){
    printPane = editorPane;
}
```

I believe the applet runner infrastructure expects a public *parameterless* constructor. Where are you expecting it to get a `JEditorPane` from to pass into your constructor?

Note that your `main` method is irrelevant here - that's *not* how applets are started.

Comment: Oh. I didn't realise that. Could I just move the code in the main method into the constructor then and remove the parameter?

Comment: @Liam: Well, I'd think about it a bit more carefully than that - and consider using the other lifecycle methods of `Applet` - but fundamentally you'll need to move any initialization out of `main`, yes.